# How to instruct MapStruct to use Builder without a static method

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a simple MapStruct class:

```
@Mapper
public interface SomeMapper {
    SomeDto map(SomeModel someModel);
    SomeModel map(SomeDto someDto);
}
```

The problem is, my `SomeModel` is using a `Builder` but without a static method, i.e.

```
class SomeModel {
  public static class Builder {

  }

  // there is no public static Builder builder() method available
}
```

How do I tell MapStruct that it needs to directly use the `new SomeModel.Builder()` instead of `SomeModel.builder()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box way for MapStruct to detect that `SomeModel.Builder` is the builder for `SomeModel`.

However, you could provide your own `BuilderProvider` SPI and implement the logic you want. You can read more about that [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#custom-builder-provider).